# Not able to save Image using Handler. "Physical path, but a virtual path was expected."

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to save the Image and in the application. when I save it in the local folder of the application, it saves fine but when I am trying to save it in anoher folder outside the project it gives me an error. I am using an handler to save this.

```
long recordID = "1234";
string x = context.Server.MapPath(@"C:\\Users\\Tomcrise\\Desktop\\DevNo\\imgPath\\");
var fileUploadPath = (context.Server.MapPath( x + recordID));
```

```
'C:/Users/Tomcrise/Desktop/DevNo/imgPath/482023112806'
```

is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected.

I have also tried

```
string[] fileUploadPath = Directory.GetFiles(context.Server.MapPath(x + recordID));
```

but I get the same error.
Can someone please heplp me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
long recordID = 1234;
string path = $@"C:\\Users\\Tomcrise\\Desktop\\DevNo\\imgPath\\{recordID}";
```

Comment: nope..doesn't work.

Comment: What's the error you are getting? and what exactly are you trying to achieve?